# Sinatra - Request scoped global variables?

Tags: sinatra, instrumentation

For the purposes of instrumentation, I'd like to be able to track slow bits of code and store the results in a variable (hash or whatever) that is cleared out at the beginning of each request.

In Sinatra, I know that the Sinatra::Application class is created at the beginning of each request so it's possible to create a member variable in a before block and store all my instrumentation data there. That's not quite ideal, because I'd still like to be able to use my instrumentation code from helper classes, etc.

I know there are various third party libraries that will do something similar (NewRelic), but i'd like to avoid that if i could.

Is it possible to create a request scoped global variable independent of the Sinatra::Application class/ routing infrastructure?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought about putting the instrumentation code in an [extension](http://www.sinatrarb.com/extensions.html)?